# Consumir un API REST desde C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Estoy consumiendo un API REST desde C#, con el código generado me funciona, pero me estoy quemando en la puerta del horno, no sé como obtener la información devuelta, he leído que debe ser deserializado y así ser tratada como un objeto normal, pero no logro llegar con la solución, les muestro el código.

```
var client = new RestClient("http://url");

client.Timeout = -1;

var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

request.AddHeader("channelID", "ff");

request.AddHeader("user", "fff");

request.AddHeader("password", "fffff");

request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

Por consola puedo ver los datos, hasta aquí todo está correcto, pero como extraigo cada valor del Json de la manera más optima, vuelvo y repito, el código funciona perfectamente, pero no se como tomar y manejar el Json, alguien me puede ayudar a extraer el contenido de lo cargado en la variable "**response**", gracias de antemano.

Comment: si, es muy facil, tenes que deserealizar el json a tu objeto, en dos lineas lo haces, puede ser con la libreria Newtonsoft.Json que es muy usada o .Net te provee tambien una libreria.

Comment: Saludos, mi hermano esas son las dos líneas que no entiendo, me tiene buscando por toda la Internet pero entiendo el tema de Deserializar, todo objeto o variable que pongo en la sección < >, si me brindas un ejemplo claro te lo agradeceré enormemente, gracias.

Comment: Te deje la respuesta, con detalles.

Comment: No podrás compartir el JSON para poder ayudarte mejor, o igual si compartes la API, sería mucho mejor

Answer (score 0):

Utilizas esta libreria que te otorga .Net o usas Newtonsoft.Json desde los Nuget

```
   using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

   // Con esta clase podes deserealizar o serializar.
   JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
```

Tenes que reemplazar MiClase, por el objeto que tu quieras y asegurarte que el response.Content tenga el texto y que no te falte obtener la cadena desde ese content suponiendo que tenes un Stream.

```
    var j = serializer.Deserialize<MiClase>(response.Content);
```

Luego en la variable j, tendras todas tus propiedades cargadas con informacion, si tu informacion es un `array` o `List<T>`

```
    var j = serializer.Deserialize<List<MiClase>>(response.Content);
```

y podras recorrer j con un foreach o una consulta de Linq.